# how to declare a new variable in vvar.h |create a vdso in linux

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to declare a new variable in `vvar.h` and define it near my new VDSO function. So that I could use this variable in my vdso function.

I have a trouble about VVar. According to the description in `arch/x86/include/asm/vvar.h`, when I declare here a new variable as `DECLARE_VVAR(0, int, count)`, I should use `DEFINE_VVAR(type, name)` to define this variable somewhere else.

The problem is after I defined this variable somewhere else, like `DEFINE_VVAR(int, count)`, when I am trying to assign an integer value to this variable `count`, it is failed. This is because after kernel version 5.2 `#define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name)` has been changed from `#define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name) type name` to `#define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name) type name[CS_BASES]`. Right now this variable `count` is an integer array instead of type integer. Therefore I can't assign a integer value to it. Do you know how to fix it?

VVAR.h: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/arch/x86/include/asm/vvar.h#L43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECLARE_VVAR` and `DEFINE_VVAR` are arch-specific vDSO implementation details, and you shouldn’t use them to add new vDSO data.

To add a vDSO variable, you should modify `struct vdso_data` [`include/vdso/datapage.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/include/vdso/datapage.h) (you’ll see the relevance of the array construction there; it’s tied to clock sources, hence the reference to `CS_BASES`), or if it’s arch-specific, the relevant `include/asm/vdso/data.h` file (currently, [s390 is the only architecture with arch-specific vDSO data in such a file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/arch/s390/include/asm/vdso/data.h); other architectures have different approaches, see [PowerPC for one](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/arch/powerpc/include/asm/vdso_datapage.h)).

Comment: Thanks, this is what i tried yesterday. After i added my new variable in this struct. I try to update this variable in 'void update_vsyscall(struct timekeeper *tk)'(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/time/vsyscall.c#L72). But i am a little bit confused about how to update it.  Because "struct vdso_data *vdata " in this fuc is a struct array.  Where is my variable in the array vdata 。 in which index? the array size is 2. i am not sure my variable is in vdata[0] or vdata[1].

Comment: The `vdata` there is specific to clock sources (that’s what `CS` stands for). If your variable isn’t clock-source-dependent, it shouldn’t be an array...

Comment: my variable is a simple variable ,not clock-source-dependent. i just want to implement a vdso call and a system call. in system call i will update this variable ,then i can see the update result by vdso call.

Comment: but i am not sure what do you mean by "it shouldn’t be an array". Because if i modify the struct vdso_data in include/vdso/datapage.h, then this struct "vdso_data " will be defined by macro #define DEFINE_VVAR(type, name) type name[CS_BASES]  in  x86/include/asm/vdso/vsyscall.h(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/vdso/vsyscall.h#L13) . After that whenever i try to get this variable "vdso_data " using "__arch_get_k_vdso_data" (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/vdso/vsyscall.h#L13), it is a array. Am i not correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my comment doesn’t make any sense, as you say it’s the overall struct that ends up in an array. As a workaround, you probably need to hard-code a 0 index (always use `vdata[0]` for your variable).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a PPC-style arch-specific struct, see `arch/powerpc/include/asm/vdso_datapage.h` (but that would require far more changes on x86).

Comment: okay. thanks. this is helpful. since i am a beginner, i would use vdata[0] to keep my variable.