# How to read symbol value directly from memory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, environment-variables, memory

**So what I need to do is read a kernel symbol directly from physical memory.** I wrote a kernel module that exports a variable (symbol) using the following lines

```
int test_var = 5;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(test_var);
```

Using `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep test_var` I get

```
ffffffffc04d6064 r __kstrtab_test_var   [smigenerator]
ffffffffc04d606d r __kstrtabns_test_var [smigenerator]
ffffffffc04d6054 r __ksymtab_test_var   [smigenerator]
ffffffffc04d7000 D test_var [smigenerator]
```

So my symbol is stored at `0xc04d7000`. If I run `sudo devmem2 0xc04d7000` I'll get its value (=5), right?

Wrong! Reading that address returns `0xFF300A24`. **Why am I not getting the variable's value when I read the memory address where it's supposed to be stored??**

I've read something about kernel base address and about this address obtained from kallsyms being an offset that should be added to the kernel base address, Not sure if that's true, but in case it is, how can I get this kernel base address?

This might be a dumb question, but I'm totally new to kernel and its concepts and didn't find any answers that could help me.

For the record I'm on Ubuntu 22, kernel 5.15.0-52-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol is stored at the virtual address `ffffffffc04d7000` (ignoring layout randomisation, but that doesn’t matter here ultimately), in kernel memory, and it’s inaccessible from userspace.

If you want to make a variable accessible (read-only) in userspace, you should make it available through the vDSO; look at how [`gettimeofday`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c) is implemented. See also [how to declare a new variable in vvar.h |create a vdso in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650350/86440).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So not even a "DMA program" like devmem2 can access that `ffffffffc04d7000` address? What if I try to access that address through another kernel module or an SMM driver (being ring 0 and ring -2, respectively) by creating a pointer to that address and retrieving the value from the pointer, you think that might work?

Comment: `devmem2` (like any access through `/dev/mem`) uses physical addresses, so you’d have to figure out what physical address your variable is stored at. `/dev/mem` is handled by a kernel device driver, so accesses using that still go through the kernel. You could use another kernel module (which would only have to reference the exported symbol anyway), or a SMM driver, yes.

Comment: Great! Will definitely give both a try (ko and SMM). I thought this `ffffffffc04d7000` was a physical address, that's why I expected `devmem2` would read it just fine. Thanks again for the help, man!